# Installing only devDependencies - `swagger-express-middleware` prevents `glob` from installing

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, glob

I am trying to install the `glob` module and have encountered a weird bug I can't seem to make sense of.

Package.json (this isn't a snippet, this is the whole file for the purposes of replicating the problem):

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "glob": "^7.1.6"
  }
}
```

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -euxo pipefail

rm -rf node_modules || true    # remove folder if present
rm package-lock.json || true   # remove lockfile if present
npm install --only=development # install devDependencies only
ls node_modules/glob           # check whether glob was installed
```

This works as expected - `glob` is installed, the contents of the `glob` folder are printed to the screen, and everybody's happy.

But when I put `swagger-express-middleware` in the main `dependencies` section:

Package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "swagger-express-middleware": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "glob": "^7.1.6"
  }
}
```

And run the same bash script as above, then I get the following error:

`ls: node_modules/glob: No such file or directory`

In other words, the `glob` module never got installed, even though the only difference was the presence of a dependency that wasn't even installed either, since we specifically only installed dev dependencies anyway via `npm install --only=development`.

Why might this be the case? I cannot for the life of me figure out why the presence of `swagger-express-middleware` (and no other modules are doing this, mind you) would prevent `glob` from being installed.

Are there any other examples of conflicts like this?

Device details, in case it makes a difference: macOS Catalina 10.15.7, NPM 6.14.8, Node 12.18.2

Comment: When I `npm i --only=dev`, `node_modules/` doesn't get created at all, despite `package-lock.json` listing resolved dependencies...

Comment: Thanks for testing.

That's right, there's no `node_modules` folder getting created. However if we remove the `swagger-express-middleware` module, then `glob` installs without issue.

You can verify that it's only `glob` not installing when `swagger-express-middleware` is present by adding another devDependency, e.g. `"mocha": "^8.1.3"` - `mocha` and its dependencies will install, but not `glob`.